# ruby's =~ operator return values?

Tags: ruby

```
def starts_with_consonant?(s)
  if /^(a|e|i|o|u).*/i =~ s
    true
  else
    false
  end
end

# prints out true
puts starts_with_consonant?('aa') 

# prints out false
puts starts_with_consonant?('da')
```

If I change the code just to

```
def starts_with_consonant?(s)
  /^(a|e|i|o|u).*/i =~ s
end
```

Is that same functionality because

```
puts starts_with_consonant?('aa').inspect
```

prints out 0 (Shouldn't it be 1?)

```
puts starts_with_consonant?('da').inspect
```

prints out nil

```
# both print out 0
 puts starts_with_consonant?('aa').to_i
 puts starts_with_consonant?('da').to_i
```

What gives?

Comment: Wouldn't "starts with a consonant" regex look more like `/^[b-df-hj-np-tv-z]/i`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first method, with the if/else statement, is treating the result of the `=~` check as "*truthy value or not?*". If the match is found in the string, it returns the index (in your case, `0`) or if it is not found, it returns `nil`.

`0` is a truthy value; `nil` is not.

Therefore, even though it's returning the same result in each of your methods containing the `/.../ =~ s` expression, you get different return values out of the methods, depending on what you do with that result.

In the if/else statement, you get `true` when it's the truthy value of `0`, and `false` when it's the non-truthy value of `nil`.

In the bare return statement, you get the plain return values of `0` and `nil`.

Answer (score 1):

The `=~` operator returns the first match index if the `String` and `Regexp` match, otherwise `nil` is returned:

```
'foo' =~ /bar/ # => nil

'foo bar' =~ /bar/ # => 4
```

Answer (score 0):

well the [#=~](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/Regexp.html#method-i-3D-7E) method actually returns the index where the first match occurs.

You can't do `nil.to_i` because that produces zero.

```
[6] pry(main)> nil.to_i
=> 0
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> puts starts_with_consonant?('aa').inspect
> ```
>
> prints out 0 (Shouldn't it be 1?)

No, it should be `0`. Strings are zero-indexed, the pattern has been found on the zeroth position. `0` is a truthy value, triggering the `if` clause if evaluated there. `'da' =~ /a/` would return `1`, since `a` is the 1st character in the string (`d` being 0th).

> ```
> puts starts_with_consonant?('da').inspect
> ```
>
> prints out nil

There is no position that matches the pattern, so the return value is `nil`, a falsy value, which triggers the `else` clause if evaluated as an `if` condition.

> ```
> # both print out 0
> puts starts_with_consonant?('aa').to_i
> puts starts_with_consonant?('da').to_i
> ```

Because both `0.to_i` and `nil.to_i` result in `0`.

Answer (score 0):

Your getting back truthy.  You can't print it but you can use it, e.g.

```
2.0.0-p247 :007 > if "aaaabcd" =~ /a/ then puts "true" end
true
 => nil 

2.0.0-p247 :008 > if "aaaabcd" =~ /aaa/ then puts "true" end
true
 => nil 

2.0.0-p247 :009 > if "aaaabcd" =~ /z/ then puts "true" end
 => nil
```

Similarly you can set a variable based on the evaluation, i.e.

```
2.0.0-p247 :013 >   if "aaaabcd" =~ /a/ then b=1 end
 => 1 

2.0.0-p247 :014 > if "aaaabcd" =~ /aaa/ then b=1 end
 => 1 

2.0.0-p247 :015 > if "aaaabcd" =~ /zzz/ then b=1 end
 => nil
```